# One Hot Encode columns with categorical data

Tags: machine-learning

I have a couple of survey datasets that I am loading into Mathematica to do behavioral clustering.

I have columns of responses (Strings) where the users was given a fixed set of responses. The surveys are really high dimensions so I can't manually go through every question type and assign a value to each string in each one of these columns.

Is there a way I could encode the responses into numbers and do this for each column that has categorical responses like this?

For each column that looks like this
food["apple","pear","apple","orange","pizza","pizza"] 
and convert it to
food[1,2,1,3,4,4]

Comment: see `ArrayComponents`.

Answer (score 6):

```
food = {{"apple", "pizza"}, {"pear", "pizza"}, {"apple", 
    "orange"}, {"orange", "apple"}, {"pizza", "pear"}, {"pizza", 
    "apple"}};
```

[image]

```
fe = FeatureExtraction[
   food,
   {1 -> "IntegerVector", 2 -> "IndicatorVector"},
   FeatureTypes -> <|{1, 2} -> "Nominal"|>
   ];

fe@food // TableForm
```

[image]

```
fe@{"unknown_food", "unknown_food"}
```

> {0, 0., 0., 0., 0.}

Answer (score 3):

`NetEncoder` is perfect for this:

```
encode[list_]:= NetEncoder[{"Class", DeleteDuplicates[list]}][list]

encode[{"apple","pear","apple","orange","pizza","pizza"}]

(*{1,2,1,3,4,4}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a range and and a rule to send the arguments to the range values.

```
food["apple","pear","apple","orange","pizza","pizza"]/.
 food[args___]:>With[{un=Union@{args}},With[{rng=Range@Length@un},
  food[args]/.Thread[un->rng]]]  
(*food[1,3,1,2,4,4]*)
```