# One-hot encode from Integer Encoding

Tags: list-manipulation, machine-learning

I have several data sets that I am working with in Mathematica. There are several columns of data but I am going through it one column at a time. Now I have some columns where respondents were able to click only one option, and some where they were able to click several options, for example:

```
sources = {"Tumblr", "Other", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", 
"Tumblr","Other", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Tumblr", 
"Other","Other", "Tumblr", "Discord server (please specify)", 
"Tumblr","Tumblr", "Tumblr", "Other", "Other", "Direct recommendation, such 
as by a friend or family member", "Tumblr"}
```

and

```
religions = {{"Jewish"}, {"Agnostic"}, {"Atheist"}, {"Jewish", "Agnostic",
"Spiritual"}, {"Atheist"}, {"Spiritual"}, {}, {"Atheist",
"Agnostic"}, {"Spiritual"}, {"Christian - Protestant"}, {"Agnostic"},
{"Jewish"}, {"Agnostic", "Pagan - Other"}}
```

These data sets are all 9,000 to 15,000 responses long, so manually changing the responses isn't an option. I managed to use NetEncoder but think One-Hot encoding would better serve my purposes to find networks/communities, but am having difficulty thinking about how to go from the Integer to One-Hot Encoding.

So for example, the religion options were:

```
religionOpt = {"Christian - Protestant", "Christian - Catholic", "Christian 
Other", "Jewish", "Muslim", "Buddhist", "Hindu", "African Traditional
and Diasporic", "Atheist", "Agnostic", "Pagan - Nordic", "Pagan -
Kemetic", "Pagan - Hellenic", "Pagan - Other", "Spiritual", "Other
ethnic or indigenous religion", "Other"}
religionOptEnc = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
```

and the encoded data set I end up getting is (I already have a method to get it in this form):

```
religionEnc = {{4}, {10}, {9}, {4, 10, 15}, {9}, {15}, {}, {9, 
  10}, {15}, {1}, {10}, {4}, {10, 14}}
```

I saw this question [One Hot Encode columns with categorical data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158515/one-hot-encode-columns-with-categorical-data) but when I (quickly) tried to adopt it for my data, for the sources, I was getting the same results as NetEncode, and for religion I was stumped, as in this example, the data has the form

```
{{a,b},{c,d},...}
```

whereas my data sets have variable length, with options such as

```
{{a},{b,c,d},...}
```

Any advice from where to go from here would be appreciated. I initially think about tackling the problem by writing some For[] loop, but I remember reading some response on this site that in Mathematica it's usually better to avoid For[] loops if possible?

EDIT: The desired output for the sources would be:
[image]
and an example of religions would be:
[image]
and so on. I cut a lot of the rows and options since I just wanted a quick example of what I was trying to get the data to look like. I already have all the data Integer Encoded, but I'm hitting a mental block about this final step.

Comment: Would `religions /. Thread[religionOpt -> religionOptEnc]` work for you? This returns your `religionEnc` set above. Indeed, if the encoding number is always sequential, you could use `religions /. Thread[religionOpt -> Range@Length@religionOpt]`. If not, can you show us what *your desired* output should be?

Comment: @MarcoB Good idea, I'll update the post with what I desire the output to be. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following helper function generates the unique encodings as a replacement list, starting from a flat list of possible values such as `sources` or `religionOpt` in your example:

```
ClearAll[generateOneHotEncoding]
generateOneHotEncoding[list_] := Module[
  {unique, len},
  unique = DeleteDuplicates[list];
  len = Length[unique];
  Thread[unique -> IntegerDigits[2^(Range@len - 1), 2, len]]
]
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
sources /. generateOneHotEncoding[sources] // MatrixForm
```

[image: single choice output]

When multiple choices are possible, the output becomes less pretty:

```
religions /. generateOneHotEncoding[religionOpt] // TableForm[#, TableDepth -> 2] &
```

[image: multilevel output]

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you were putting in the options in your code, somehow I completely missed that. So my question is: just to confirm, but the columns for the output are in the same order as the fed in options, i.e., religionOpt?